# Magnetic field in double slit experiment using electron beams

Tags: optics, waves, double-slit-experiment, interference, wave-particle-duality

Say I have an experimental setup like this for a double slit experiment using an electron beam instead of light.
[image]
There is a magnetic field coming out from the plane of paper.

So will we get an interference pattern in this case? If yes, will it be just shifted, or have any other changes too from the one without a magnetic field?

Also, what would be the effect of changing the magnetic field's direction (for example by rotating it about an axis in the plane of paper and passing midway through the slits)

Comment: Do you know about the Lorentz-force only, or do you also know about the Aharonov-Bohm phase of electron waves?

Comment: Lorentz force only (at present).

Comment: When you do it for light, do you simply calculate the difference of the lengths of the paths of rays going through the two slits and compare it to the wavelength of the light?

Comment: Yes. That's what I do.

Comment: Then I guess you can do it similarly for the paths of the electrons, which are now influenced by the Lorentz-force. I assume the magnetic field is homogeneous in the space between the double-slit and the screen.

Comment: Ohk. And if the field is not homogenous, can we calculate the path difference using the equations from classical mechanics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brillant idea. From a theoretical point of view the intensity distribution on the observers screen should be shifted. But only an experiment could give you the irrevocable answer.

It will be an extremely important experiment if the field is executed at the top (in your experimental sketch) in one direction, and at the bottom in the opposite direction. Wish you success.